# how do i solve ModuleNotFoundError in python?

Tags: python

I'm still a newbie in python. and i keep facing this problem over and over, every time I try to run my project files in my command prompt it show me ModulNotFound!
I tried many solutions from other web pages but still can't solve it):
here [photo shows the error

[image: 1]

Comment: What's your folder structure and what game module are you trying to import?

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). You should also include a [mre], meaning the project structure and any setup like `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`.

Comment: It's `ModuleNotFoundError`, not `ModuleNotFound` or `ModulNotFound`

Comment: @wjandrea sorry typo.. yes that's the problem

Comment: @AndrewWei my folder structure is in the photo above. but it's like this: game\characters\player, i was trying to import the player module

Comment: I think you just have to do like this: `from characters import players`

Comment: @wjandrea sorry for too many errors in my post still new here, thanks for the guide though (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `main.py` instead of

```
from game.characters import player
```

try

```
from .characters import player  # there's a dot before 'characters' to refer to 
                                # the current location (relative import)
```

since `main.py` **module** and `characters` **package** (because of `__init__.py`) are in the same level/location